# query result using codeIgniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

It is the first time for me to use codeIgniter, I tried to build a simple DB driven application.
First the model:

```
class News_model extends CI_Model {

public function __construct()
{
    $this->load->database();
}

public function get_news()
   {

    $query = $this->db->get('news');
    return $query->result_array();

   }
   }
```

second the controller

```
class News extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct()
{
parent::__construct();
$this->load->model('news_model');
}

public function index()
{
$data['news'] = $this->news_model->get_news();
$data['title'] = 'News archive';

$this->load->view('templates/header', $data);
$this->load->view('news/index', $data);
$this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

The view "index":

```
<?php foreach ($news as $news_item): ?>

 <h2><?php echo $news_item['title'] ?></h2>
 <div id="main">
    <?php echo $news_item['text'] ?>
 </div>
 <p><a href="news/<?php echo $news_item['slug'] ?>">View article</a></p>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

When I run the code it displays the header and the footer, but no database record is displayed.
If I put a print statement in the view outside the foreach it works, but not inside the foreach.
I use if($news) to find out if the query retrieved any result, but there is no result retrieved.

How can I know why there is no result retrieved from the DB?

Comment: use if (empty($news)) to check if any results were retrieved.

Comment: it is empty, but i don't know why? i inserted some records into the database.

Comment: What do you mean by "if I put the print outside foreach it works"? the $news variable is no longer empty?

Comment: if i put the print statement before foreeach i can see the print statement output but not inside foreach. i was trying to know if the view was loaded or not. i found that the view is loaded but $news variable always empty. it seems that the query always retrieve nothing. and i do not know what is the problem with the query, why it retrieved nothing? :(

Comment: thank you everyone.the problem was misspelling of the database.php variable value :p

Answer (score 0):

You need to call another foreach inside your foreach. example:

```
foreach ($result as $row) {
        foreach ($row as $key => $val) {
            if ($key === "reservation_info") {
                $data['decoded'] = json_decode($val);
            } else {
                $data[$key] = $val;
            }
        }
    }
```

and i would use the '$val' values in the view. just by calling them as variables, like so

```
//in the view
echo $decoded
echo $firtname
```

... and so on

Answer (score 0):

to check if new is empty or not, just

```
print_r($news);
```

or you can modify your view :

```
<?php if(!empty($new)): ?>
  <?php foreach ($news as $news_item): ?>

   <h2><?php echo $news_item['title'] ?></h2>
   <div id="main">
      <?php echo $news_item['text'] ?>
   </div>
   <p><a href="news/<?php echo $news_item['slug'] ?>">View article</a></p>

  <?php endforeach ?>
<?php else: ?>
  Empty news 
<?php endif; ?>
```